# Autoloader finding file but not class

Tags: php, symfony

I'm sorry I read all the many threads about this error, but still can't find where I'm failing.

The error states:

```
The autoloader expected class "TP\MainBundle\Form\ContactoType" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\TP/src\TP\MainBundle\Form\ContactoType.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

My routing.yml is

```
contacto_new:
    pattern: /new
    defaults: { _controller: TPMainBundle:default:new }
```

My file 'Contacto.php' is under TP/src/TP/MainBundle/Entity and the first lines of code are:

```
<?php
namespace TP\MainBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

And my 'ContactoType.php' is under TP/src/TP/MainBundle/Form/ContactoType.php

It's code is:

```
<?php
namespace Tp\MainBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
class CursoType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder->add('name');
$builder->add('email');
$builder->add('message'); }
public function getName()
{
return 'contacto_form';
}
}
```

And my Action in DefaultController is:

```
public function newAction()
{
$contacto = new Contacto();
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactoType(), $contacto);
return $this->render('TPMainBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView(),
));
}

}
```

I can't understand where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ContactoType.php should containt the same named class, instead it has the CursoType class.